# Map SDK for IOS and Place API (Reverse Geocoding to get the User's current location details)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am doing an delivery app on both iOS and Android.
Here is the flow.

1. User has to add their current location to their address book.
2. When adding the address, user will be directed to a map.
3. User can move the "Marker" on the map to adjust their location or just simply click an button to auto locate their location.
4. When the "Marker" is pointed on a specific address, for example, shop, it will display the shop name and full address of the shop. Same goes to the housing area.

So, my question is, if i am using reverse geocoding (reverseGeocodeCoordinate - Maps SDK for iOS), it only able to return the address. What if I also want to get the place name?

Now i am using reverse geocoding, but it doesn't return with the place name, only address is available

Comment: Is it possible to reverse geocoding for location which only has place id? if the place has no place id, then it will return to the nearest location which has place id

Answer (score 0):

If you allow users to use Coordinate (choose a point on Gmap) to set their address, then fetch the address component and detail information from that Coordinate.

You can use this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#reverse-example